# pynetdicom on_association_requested() get request type (C_FIND, C_ECHO etc)

Tags: python, pynetdicom

I'm not able to find the variable that holds the Message Type in event name, "on_association_requested" and "on_association_released" methods. If we give event.event.name it results in "EVT_REQUESTED" or "EVT_RELEASED".

INCOMING DIMSE MESSAGE

D: Message Type                  : C-ECHO RQ

D: Presentation Context ID       : 1

D: Message ID                    : 1

D: Data Set                      : None

END OF DIMSE MESSAGE

I tried to get the Message Type, I was not able to find how.

Answer (score 0):

There is no DIMSE message type during association request. Only after an association has already been through request and acceptance are DIMSE messages allowed to be sent.

Comment: I want to validate CalledAET , Calling AET, Host IP in the association requested method for all operations except C_ECHO. Same in the association release method. How do I do this ?

In association released method, I want to perform additional actions for all operations except C_ECHO, how do I distinguish them ?

Comment: For the first part, you can't - there's no way to know ahead of time if the peer will send a C-ECHO request over an association. For the second part you'll need to track which DIMSE requests were sent and perform your additional actions accordingly.

Comment: How can we track which DIMSE requests were sent?

Comment: You could try binding a function to [evt.EVT_DIMSE_RECV](https://pydicom.github.io/pynetdicom/stable/reference/generated/pynetdicom._handlers.doc_handle_dimse.html#pynetdicom._handlers.doc_handle_dimse), in combination with a variable that you store request types and clear out when the association ends.